# Frequent '503 - Service Unavailable' responses from Google Proximity API v1beta1

Tags: google-api, eddystone, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform, google-proximity-api

We (Beaconstac - https://www.beaconstac.com) are seeing an increasing number of Proximity API requests returning '503 - Service Unavailable' errors.

For instance: 
`<HttpError 503 when requesting https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beacons/3!5dc33487f02e477d4058ac233f25592d/attachments:batchDelete?projectId=beaconstac-1043&alt=json&namespacedType=com.google.nearby%2F%2A returned "The service is currently unavailable.">`.

It seems occur at random intervals where all the requests to the API fail at the same time and then start back up normally after a few seconds or so.

We did raise an issue with Google regarding this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110375283) and they in-turn redirected us to post the issue on stackoverflow. Is anybody else experiencing the same issue as us?

Comment: 503 errors are typically caused by servers being taken offline (or put into maintenance mode) for periods of time.  The fact that you are getting these regularly, however, suggests more of a server-side bug than anything else.    I'm not sure why they thought posting on StackOverflow would be helpful, as the general community has no insight into closed-source Google server software.  If this happens randomly and recovers in a few seconds or so, I would suggest simply making your client retry automatically.  As long as it works, what does it matter if it worked on a retry?

Comment: Exactly, seems weird that Google thought the open-source community will be able to assist in this. We are looking at options where the server retries the requests incase of errors, but it just seems a lot of work where it should be needed considering we are working with Google APIs and developers have a certain amount of expectation from them.

Comment: I agree completely.  In my opinion, this falls into the category of things you just have to accept, because building a retry client (while a pain) is easier than yelling at a brick wall.